# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found, exception error

Tags: java, file, logging

i want to search in a file for a given password given from user input and and i get a runtime exception when i run the project here is my code:

```
public static Boolean check_username_and_password(String fileName, String password) throws IOException
{
    String[] words = null;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader (fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String s;
String input = password;
int count = 0;
while((s=br.readLine()) != null)
{
    words = s.split(" ");
    for(String word : words) {
        if(word.equals(input))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
if (count != 0) {
    return true;
}

else 
{
    return false;
}
}

public static void EmpLogin() throws IOException
{
    Scanner y = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
    String password = y.nextLine();
    if (check_username_and_password("C:/Users/moham/OneDrive/Desktop/ss", password) == true)
    {
        System.out.println("logged in"); 
    }
    
    else
    {   
        System.out.println("invalid!"); 
    }
}
```

i am trying to make a code to login for bank employees, and here is the error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

```
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Hello/Hello.EmployeeDetails.EmpLogin(Main_class.java:113)
    at Hello/Hello.EmployeeDetails$Employee.main(Main_class.java:181)
```

Comment: How can anyone help without including your `check_username_and_password` method? The code you've posted here is surely not where the problem is. Include your exception as well, ideally pointing out the line that the error occured on.

Comment: I can guess at the issue: did you create more than one `Scanner`? If so, don't do that (create a single one for `System.in`, and re-use it). Otherwise, would need to see the `#main` method under your `Employee` nested class.

Comment: @Rogue how can i use the same scanner twice and i am using one in the main and one outside it?

Comment: You're using quite a bit of static currently (which I think may have a better way), but for `Scanner`, it is one of the few times I actually recommend a static field: `static final Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);`, which can then be used by other functions wanting to read stdin. This should usually be managed by a single thread, but I don't believe that's at issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You've closed `System.in`, probably by closing the scanner. Do not do that.

*But, my IDE is yelling at me, something about 'unclosed resources' or whatnot!*

Your IDE is wrong; known 'bug' in IDEs, they don't understand the notion that filterstreams around resources you aren't responsible for closing, should never be closed. It doesn't come up much, *except* `new Scanner(System.in)`.

A few general hints:

### Perhaps use console

The console object has the ability to ask for passwords and echoes nothing, or stars. `System.getConsole()` is how you get it, and [here is the Console API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html).

Note that in general the 'mini console' in IDEs that is used when you run a java app inside it, doesn't work with console, only System.in, which is kinda silly but as far as I can tell not (yet) up for getting fixed in upcoming java versions. IDEs perhaps need to step up and fix this.

### If not... pass Scanner around

Java methods can take arguments. So, take the scanner as argument:

```
public static void EmpLogin(Scanner scanner) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
    String password = scanner.nextLine();
    if (check_username_and_password("C:/Users/moham/OneDrive/Desktop/ss", password))
    {
        System.out.println("logged in"); 
    }
    
    else
    {   
        System.out.println("invalid!"); 
    }
```

### `== true` is silly, remove it

`x == true` is valid java only if `x` is itself a boolean expression. Meaning, `x` is true or false. This boils down to `if true is true, then..` which is silly. `== true` can always just be lopped off, in java.

### But `new FileReader` IS a resource

> `FileReader fr = new FileReader (fileName);`

This is buggy java code; you're opening a resource without closing it. Your app will crash soon after if you repeatedly do this. The only way to safely open resources is as follows:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName) {
  .. code that uses fr here ..
}
```

This ensures `fr` is closed, no matter how code exits that block (by running to the end, or `return`, or an exception - no matter).